# Add root folder onto URL Using Regex

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm trying to transform any URL in PHP and add a root folder onto it using regex.

Before:

`http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/`

After:

`http://domainNamehere.com/es/event/test-event-in-the-future/`

Any ideas?

Comment: Transform where? Just in a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution without regex:

```
$root_folder = 'es';
$url = "http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/";

$p = strpos($url, '/', 8);
$url_new = sprintf('%s/%s/%s', substr($url, 0, $p), $root_folder, substr($url, $p+1));
```

---

**EDIT**: JavaScript solution is pretty much the same:

```
var root_folder = 'es';
var url = "http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/";

var p = url.indexOf('/', 8);
var url_new = url.substring(0,p) + '/' + root_folder + url.substring(p);
```

Of course, for a live application you should also check if `p` actually gets a valid value assigned (that means if the slash is found) because you might have an invalid url in your input or empty string.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly!  Any idea how to do something similar in jQuery/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://domainNamehere.com/event/test-event-in-the-future/'; //or the function you use to grab it;
$url = str_replace('domainNamehere.com','domainNamehere.com/es', $url);
```

quite dirty but effective and without regex, assuming your "es" folder is always in that position (I think so)

Comment: This will not catch: `www.domainNamehere.com`.

Comment: Now our answer is quite the same ;D Good job.

Comment: Well, actually, using str_replace() answer couldn't be much different...OP didn't specify having a www before the url, so I just oversaw that! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the domain name is always the same you can use:

```
$string = str_replace('domainNamehere.com', 'domainNamehere.com/es', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
$url = preg_replace('#(?<=^[a-z]+://[^/]+/)#i', "es/", $url);
```

Use '#' to delimit the regular expression so the slashes don't have to be escaped.

`(?<=...)` searches for a match for `[a-z]://[^/]+/` without including it in the matched string.

`[a-z]+://[^/]/` matches a sequence of letters followed by `://` followed by non-slashes, then a slash.  This will handle all web protocols, particularly `http` and `https`.

The little `i` makes the search case-insensitive.

The replacement just inserts `es/` after the match.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `<b>Warning</b>:  preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Unknown modifier '/' in <b>functions.php</b> on line <b>108</b><br />`

Answer (score 0):

This is the most succinct way that I could think of how to do it.

```
$new_url = preg_replace('#(?<=\w)(?=/)#', '/en', $url, 1);
```

It will insert whatever you put in the 2nd parameter into the string just before the first slash that also has a proceeding alphanumeric character.

Tested with PHP 5.3.6